# Spinnaker - Clouddriver redis exception

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

Trying to deploy Spinnaker using Halyard.

Getting the below error from Clouddriver and it fails to start.

2020-03-01 06:03:29.942 ERROR 8 --- [gentScheduler-1] c.n.s.c.r.c.ClusteredAgentScheduler      : Unable to run agents

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:53) ~[jedis-2.9.3.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:226) ~[jedis-2.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.spinnaker.kork.jedis.telemetry.InstrumentedJedisPool.getResource(InstrumentedJedisPool.java:61) ~[kork-jedis-1.17.x-iss.1.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.spinnaker.kork.jedis.telemetry.InstrumentedJedisPool.getResource(InstrumentedJedisPool.java:27) ~[kork-jedis-1.17.x-iss.1.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.spinnaker.kork.jedis.JedisClientDelegate.withCommandsClient(JedisClientDelegate.java:45) ~[kork-jedis-1.17.x-iss.1.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.spinnaker.cats.redis.cluster.ClusteredAgentScheduler.acquireRunKey(ClusteredAgentScheduler.java:178) ~[cats-redis-1.17.x-iss.4.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.spinnaker.cats.redis.cluster.ClusteredAgentScheduler.acquire(ClusteredAgentScheduler.java:131) ~[cats-redis-1.17.x-iss.4.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.spinnaker.cats.redis.cluster.ClusteredAgentScheduler.runAgents(ClusteredAgentScheduler.java:158) ~[cats-redis-1.17.x-iss.4.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.spinnaker.cats.redis.cluster.ClusteredAgentScheduler.run(ClusteredAgentScheduler.java:151) ~[cats-redis-1.17.x-iss.4.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pool not open
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.BaseGenericObjectPool.assertOpen(BaseGenericObjectPool.java:759) ~[commons-pool2-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:402) ~[commons-pool2-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:349) ~[commons-pool2-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:49) ~[jedis-2.9.3.jar:na]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

I am able reach redis from Clouddriver pod.

```
nc -vz spin-redis 6379
```

Is there any other config missing?

Comment: post your halyard config. Are you deploying to local-debian or Kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest for you to upgrade to latest/stable version i.e. 1.18.X

- Set the version you want to use. Refer to the releases page [Versions](https://www.spinnaker.io/community/releases/versions/)

  export UPGRADE_VERSION=1.18.5
  hal config version edit --version $UPGRADE_VERSION
- Deploy and apply the new version with `hal`

  hal deploy apply